# Include CSS in HTML with Google app script

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

Im trying to build a small app with google app script which will work as an inventory with login
im working with HTML and CSS but facing difficulty in connecting both

when i try this in browser, nothing is shown

this is my structure [image: Structure]

my code.gs is like this

```
    function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
    }
```

My html script goes like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>    
    <html>    
     <head>    
       <base target="_top">
       <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
      </head>    
    <body>    
        <h2>Login Page</h2><br>    
        <div class="login">    
        <form id="login" method="get" action="login.php">    
            <label><b>User Name     
            </b>    
            </label>    
            <input type="text" name="Uname" id="Uname" placeholder="Username">    
            <br><br>    
            <label><b>Password     
            </b>    
            </label>    
            <input type="Password" name="Pass" id="Pass" placeholder="Password">    
            <br><br>    
            <input type="button" name="log" id="log" value="Log In Here">       
            <br><br>    
            <input type="checkbox" id="check">    
            <span>Remember me</span>    
            <br><br>    
            Forgot <a href="#">Password</a>    
        </form>     
    </div>    
    </body>    
    </html>
```

and css goes like this

```
    <style>

    body  
    {  
        margin: 0;  
        padding: 0;  
        background-color:#6abadeba;  
        font-family: 'Arial';  
    }  
    .login{  
            width: 382px;  
            overflow: hidden;  
            margin: auto;  
            margin: 20 0 0 450px;  
            padding: 80px;  
            background: #23463f;  
            border-radius: 15px ;  
              
    }  
    h2{  
        text-align: center;  
        color: #277582;  
        padding: 20px;  
    }  
    label{  
        color: #08ffd1;  
        font-size: 17px;  
    }  
    #Uname{  
        width: 300px;  
        height: 30px;  
        border: none;  
        border-radius: 3px;  
        padding-left: 8px;  
    }  
    #Pass{  
        width: 300px;  
        height: 30px;  
        border: none;  
        border-radius: 3px;  
        padding-left: 8px;  
          
    }  
    #log{  
        width: 300px;  
        height: 30px;  
        border: none;  
        border-radius: 17px;  
        padding-left: 7px;  
        color: blue;  
      
      
    }  
    span{  
        color: white;  
        font-size: 17px;  
    }  
    a{  
        float: right;  
        background-color: grey;  
    }  
    <style>
```

what could be going wrong?

I refereed this document from google https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

i changed my code to match this best practice but still having issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your `Stylesheet`, the tag of `<style>` is not correctly enclosed. In your case, `<style>,,,<style>`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. So, please modify your `Stylesheet` file as follows.

#### From:

```
a{  
    float: right;  
    background-color: grey;  
}  
<style>
```

#### To:

```
a{  
    float: right;  
    background-color: grey;  
}  
</style> <!-- Modified -->
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: i modified the style sheet, now the html script is working and displayed but css is nit getting effective,

Comment: @albetroz Thank you for replying. I understand that your question says `when i try this in browser, nothing is shown`. From `i modified the style sheet, now the html script is working and displayed`, it was found that your issue was resolved. About `but css is nit getting effective,`, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your 2nd question. I apologize for my poor English skill. When your HTML and CSS are used, it becomes as follows. https://jsfiddle.net/mcg43hpz/ What is your expected result? Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result?

Comment: yes to an extend my issue is solved, i will post an additional question for the css

Comment: @albetroz Thank you for replying. From `yes to an extend my issue is solved`, I understood your issue was resolved. About `i will post an additional question for the css`, I understood it.